# ASP.NET text box, set focus border color in external CSS file

Tags: asp.net, css

I have an ASP.NET text box. I am trying to set the color of the border to green when the textbox gains focus, and I want to be specific about the **class** of the textbox. The text box looks like this -

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="myInput" BorderStyle="None"  runat="server">Search</asp:TextBox>
```

**NOTE**: I have BorderStyle="None" to start with, because when the textbox does not have focus, I want *no* border showing. Currently a border is shown on focusing, but it's not the color I want.

I have tried the following in my CSS file -

```
.myInput:focus {
                 border: green;
              }
```

and

```
input.myInput:focus {

                    border: green;
                }
```

(and a few others) but nothing has worked. Can someone please tell me how it can be done?
Thanks!

Comment: instead of border did try using border-color: if you only want to change its color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use -

```
 .myInput:focus {
        border:solid 1px green !important;
 }
```

Because the border style was being overridden by other CSS settings.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you need to remove the `BorderStyle="None"` from your `TextBox` control.

Set the `border` style for this in CSS, then you can use the `focus`

Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/xXEWK/

you can't see the textbox at first - click just to the right of where you see 'Textbox ->'

Comment: I have BorderStyle="None" to start with, because when the textbox does not have focus, I want no border showing. Currently a border is shown on focusing, but it's not the color I want.

Comment: yes, and that's whats stopping the green border appearing. you need to set this in the CSS. Have a look at the fiddle i posted, it will show you. CSS is on the right, textbox on the left.

Comment: Thanks Darren! There was a border appearing, it was just the wrong color. Turns out it was being overridden by other CSS.

Comment: If this answered your Q, please mark it, this helps others as well as gets your accept rating up :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TSx7m/)

Instead of  `border: green` you need to use `border: 1px solid green;`

And your text box should be like this

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="myInput"  runat="server">Search</asp:TextBox>
```

**Update**

I think then its better to use jQuery.

You can add a class on foucus and remove the class when out focus

See more about [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) and [focusOut](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

See this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/TSx7m/1/)

Comment: he also needs to remove border="none" for it to work. If you add Style="border:none;" to your input in your fiddle, it won't change colour on focus

Comment: See, this is why I set the border to 0px on my fiddle; he clearly didn't want a border to start with.. :)

Comment: I have BorderStyle="None" to start with, because when the textbox does not have focus, I want no border showing. Currently a border is shown on focusing, but it's not the color I want.

Comment: @ABogus: Updated the answer. Please have a look

Comment: Thanks huMpty duMpty! There was a border appearing, it was just the wrong color. Turns out it was being overridden by other CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" CSSClass="myInput" runat="server">Search</asp:TextBox>
```